# Using php Reflection API to make dynamic getters and setters

Tags: php, reflection

I have some classes that do have a lot of properties!

Instead of creating a lot of getters and setters foreach class I decided to create an abstract class as templeate where I have a magic function `__call` to set and get properties values using `Php Reflection API` like below:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{
    //Check to see if we are getting a property value.
    if (preg_match("/get/i", $name)) {
        //Normalize method name, in case of camel case.
        $name = strtolower($name);

        //Find the start of get/set in the method.
        $pos = strpos($name, "get") + strlen("get");

        //Strip get / set from method. Get only property name.
        $name = substr($name, $pos, strlen($name) - $pos);

        //Refelct child class object.
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this);

        //Get child class properties.
        $props = $reflection->getProperties();

        //Loop through the init. class properties.
        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            //Check if the property its array so we can search the keys in an array.
            if (is_array($this->{$prop->getName()})) {
                //So it's an array, check if array property has the key that we are looking for.
                if (array_key_exists($name, $this->{$prop->getName()})) {
                    return $this->{$prop->getName()}[$name];
                }

            }
            //If its not array then check for the property name that we are looking for.
            else if ($prop->getName() == $name) {
                return $this->$name;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
    //Same thing here same like in get method, but instead of getting the method
    //here we will be setting a property value.
    else if (preg_match("/set/i", $name)) {
        $name  = strtolower($name);
        $pos   = strpos($name, "set") + strlen("set");
        $name  = substr($name, $pos, strlen($name) - $pos);
        $value = "";

        //Make sure that we have an argument in there.
        if (count($args) >= 1) {
            $value = $args[0];
        }

        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $props      = $reflection->getProperties();

        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            if (is_array($this->{$prop->getName()})) {

                if (array_key_exists($name, $this->{$prop->getName()})) {
                    $this->{$prop->getName()}[$name] = $value;
                }

            } else if ($prop->getName() == $name) {
                $this->$name = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My questions is:

> Is this a good approach to make dynamic getters and setters or what
>   are the downsides of this compare to child classes getters and
>   setters! And what is the best way of handling not found properties
>   throwing an exception or return null ?

Comment: Not sure if it's good or bad, downsides include typing mistakes and the IDE not doing autocompletion.  One essential thing I think though is to store the reflected properties in a class property rather than continually loading them each time, this is a big overhead.

Comment: Could you be a lil bit more specific how do you think to store reflected properties in a class property ? I have 20 classes extending this abstract class

Comment: If you created a `$this->props` value in this code, when you get to the the reflection part, check if it's set (and has a value) if not - do the reflection part and store the result in `$this->props`, if it is set, then just run with it.

Comment: @NigelRen ah right, what do you think which is the best way to handle not found property throwing exception or returning null ?